# How to change the visibility of a <div> tag using javascript in the same page?

Tags: javascript, html, css, css-transitions

I'm working on a simple javascript code.

***Based on the condition I should change the visibility of the  tag from hidden to visible.***

I should use javascript alone. No jQuery or AJAX. Any idea or suggestion please.

Comment: You can do it using only CSS3, or using JavaScript can You use `jsfiddle.net` to put code and give us some link?

Answer (score 34, accepted):

### Using the `visibility` attribute:

Show the div with `id="yourID"`:

```
document.getElementById("yourID").style.visibility = "visible";
```

To hide it:

```
document.getElementById("main").style.visibility = "hidden";
```

### Using the `display` attribute:

Show:

```
document.getElementById("yourID").style.display= "block";
```

Hide:

```
document.getElementById("yourID").style.display= "none";
```

Answer (score 4):

```
<div id="contentDiv">
    This is the content .
</div>
```

if you want to change the visibility of div with id="contentDiv" using javascript then you can do with..

```
var eleDiv = document.getElementById("contentDiv");


    // based on condition you can change visibility
if(eleDiv.style.display == "block") {
        eleDiv.style.display = "none";
}
else {
    eleDiv .style.display = "block";
}
```

Hope this code helps you........

Answer (score 2):

Though asked not to be done with jquery, but can be done as: `$('.my_div_tag_id').css('visibility','hidden');`

Answer (score 1):

Visible:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("IdOfEl");
elem.style.display="block";
```

Hide:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("IdOfEl");
elem.style.display="none";
```

Comment: this is not the same as settings `visibility`.

Answer (score 1):

Call this function when you want to show the div. Write that conditions in your segment/case.

```
function showDiv() {
    document.getElementById('divId').style.display = 'block';   //  or 'inline'
}
```

Let me know your feedback.

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this would be to create the control logic in JavaScript and add it in the "script" tag of the document. Then apply the logic to hide/show the "div" element.

I created an example HTML document based on “A First HTML Document” on page 16 (Musciano and Kennedy, 2002). It includes a "div" tag within the "body" tag near the top. The ShowAndHide function has been included in the "script" tag within the "head" tag. An application of the ShowAndHide may be found in the other "script" tag within the "body" tag near the end.

You can find the HTML example as an attachment to the PDF document "[Show-and-Hide Control Logic: Inspired by a Question at Stack Overflow](https://www.academia.edu/40283015/Show-and-Hide_Control_Logic_Inspired_by_a_Question_at_Stack_Overflow)".

**Reference**

Musciano, C. and Kennedy, B. (2002). HTML and XHTML: The Definitive Guide, Fifth Edition. Sebastopol, CA: O’Reilly Media Inc.